# Angular2 Mvc5 sample application "cannot find namesapce Models" Error. How could a c# type being referenced directly in TS and it still works?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, angular, typescript

1. Download the angluar2 mvc5 sample from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4190ee5c-15d9-4afe-ac14-515bdb6493da/view/
2. then created it, restored the packages, build, done, run perfectly.
3. then I look into the code, found ERROR in the error list says: "cannot find namesapce Models".
4. double click on the error and look at the TS code in **./app/utils/HttpHelper.ts:**

   ```
   return this._http.post(path, body, options)
   .map(m => {
       var jsonresult = <Models.ViewModel.JSONReturnVM<T>>m.json();

       if (jsonresult.haserror) {
           this.errormsg = jsonresult.errormessage;
       }

       return jsonresult;
   })
   .catch(this._handleError);
   ```

Red underline under <**Models**.ViewModel.JSONReturnVM>m.json();

5. then I try to find where the hell the "Models" sits, then I found it is from a c# namespace called Model.

./Model/ViewModel/JSONReturnVM.cs

6. stop. did he just referenced a C# type into a .TS file or I was get it totally wrong or I am totally outdated and missed something wonderful entirely?
   The program run perfect, and how is that possible? If that's some new technique which can straight reference a c# type into .ts file, could I know what that is? and how to use it? Or he just did not do that and it was done by something else in the middle but I just missed it?

Please help.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere there's a generated ts (and js) file, that's getting build from the C# model. You can not reference directly to .NET classes from TypeScript.

Comment: JSONReturnVM<T> is the typescript class, it sits under wwwroot/app/Models directory.

Comment: Usually I ignore TS errors from visual studio, even blocked it

Comment: Hi @ValikhanAkhmedov Thanks for giving me tips, but I created a MVC 5 Demo and I could not found the wwwroot folder. I tried to look for similar ts class files in it but I cannot find it anywhere. Could you spot anything similar there?

Comment: wwwroot folder is present in MVC Core App not in MVC 5

Comment: @HaithamShaddad Yea I see that. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author used TypeLite. there is a TypeLite.Net4.tt file under Scripts. which generates model for .TS file to use. to my surprise the intellisense cannot find the namespace. Anyway I was wondering since when you can reference a c# in .ts but turns out to be a Nuget plug-in which auto-generate the model from a c# file to .d.ts file.